# Verificação de intervalo de datas automaticamente

Tags: javascript, html

Como faço para verificar as datas sem precisar apertar no botão enviar? Tipo colocar uma data inválida e já ser alertado se não estiver dentro do intervalo?

```js
function checarDatas() {
    var desenhoDidatico = document.desenhoDidatico;
    console.log(desenhoDidatico);
    var data_1 = new Date(desenhoDidatico.datainicial.value);
    var data_2 = new Date(desenhoDidatico.datafinal.value);
    if (!data_1 || !data_2) return false
    if (data_1 > data_2) {
        alert("Data inserida antes do início das atividades.");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="" name="desenhoDidatico" onsubmit="return checarDatas()">
    <input type="date" name="datainicial" />
    <input type="date" name="datafinal" />
    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Coloca a validação para ser executada quando sair dos campos (evento `onblur`): `<input type="date" name="datainicial" onblur="checarDatas()" />`. Veja se isso já te atende

Comment: Devo retirar o onsubmit="return checarDatas()" da tag form?

Comment: Não precisa, pode deixar, porque vai validar ao sair dos campos com data (colocar o evento nos dois) e também ao submeter o formulário. Só seria interessante, no caso da validação ao sair dos campos mudar um pouco a função, ou fazer outro, para que posso voltar no campo (focus) para fazer com que seja corrigido, ou até adicionar uma borda vermelha avisando que tem erro. Claro, isso são só ideias, sugestões

Comment: Ok, deu certo dessa forma. Mas só aparece o alert quando seleciona outro campo do formulário

Comment: Para comparar as duas datas, ambos os campos tem que estar selecionados com alguma data.

Comment: Outro problema é que `!data_1` e `!data_2` não garantem que uma data válida foi inserida.

Comment: Você usa jQuery? Se sim, pode fazer um algoritimo verificando o length de ambos os campos, para ver se ambos estão preenchidos completamente, e então, executar o código assim que ambos os campos estiverem preenchidos. Coloca o if dentro de um .trigger('change'); e o código vai executar sempre que for adicionado ou retirado um valor de dentro dos inputs. Quando ambos estiverem preenchidos, ele vai executar a função de testes automaticamente, sem você ter que retirar o foco dos campos, e podem ser preenchidos em qualquer ordem. Seria isso que você quer?

Comment: Pode ser tbm...